# What's worse, renege on an accepted offer, or work for 2 weeks then quit?

Tags: job-offer, start-date

Here's the situation, I accepted an offer then I just got a call from another company (who's know for being slow) that they are prepared to make an offer.  I like the 2nd company better, so I am tempted to renege on the first.

There's going to be a small gap between the starting dates, I know it looks bad no matter what, but would it look better to renege straight away or work two weeks at the first then tell them I don't like it and quit and go work at the 2nd company?

Answer (score 12):

Small gaps in resumes don't matter nearly as much as people think.  It only becomes a problem if the gap is so long that people question whether your skills are still current.

As for your immediate question, *in my opinion*, working for 2 weeks then quitting is much worse than backing out immediately.

In those two weeks the company will have put in significant effort to get you the tools you need (possibly buying computers, etc.), get you started on the work, introduce you to coworkers, and so on.

**If you're going to back out, do it sooner rather than later**

Answer (score 1):

The second company tells you that they're going to roll-out a job offer. But they haven't done it yet. What if they don't do it finally? It might be better to stall for time from the first company if that is possible. Just make up an excuse about you wanting to visit your family home or someone else because you are "in-between jobs and can this easily".

Once you've stalled them for 2 weeks and you get an offer letter I would recommend that you join the second company directly. This is because of the following points:

- trying out the first company for a mere 2 weeks won't be enough for you to decide. It takes time to get a "feel" of the processes, work culture.
- If there's something really bad in the first company you will likely not see it immediately.
- Due to point 2 above you are more likely to get a "goody-goody" kind of feeling in the initial days no matter which company you join. Since you say you are interested in the second company if this happens you'll feel even more confused about what to do.

So just get into the second company. You could either make up some excuse for the first company like "you need to shift to a different region" or "you just got an offer from a domain where you really really wanted to try out".